# NodeJS create JSON array for Slack incoming webhook

Tags: json, node.js

I am currently working on getting my incoming Webhook application written in Node.JS to get work with this API: https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks.

My problem is that the JSON string for Slack has to configured with `"` these quotation marks and if I create a simple JSON string in Node.JS, Slack says that the string isn't valid.

```
var text = "New Commit";
var form = '{"text": "' + text + '" }';
```

The above code works, but looks pretty ugly and when I add a `\n'` to indicate a new line, the `\n` is directly converted into a new line and not sent within the string, so Slack says again the JSON string isnt valid.

Comment: You can't just do `var obj = { text: "New commit" }` and let `JSON.stringify` take care of the qutoes?

Comment: Oh thank you very much. I should have thought of that. Everytime just doing small mistakes like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by `tandrewnichols` I need to use `JSON.stringify` and create an object.